# Can't open virtual machine in VMWare: "Binary translation is incompatible"

Tags: windows-8

I'm in a Windows 8 x64 environment and I'm trying to open a virtual machine with VMWare to use with SAS but I get these error messages

> Binary translation is incompatible with long mode on this platform. Long mode will be disabled in this virtual environment. Applications requiring long mode will not function properly as a result.
>
> See http://vmware.com/info?id=152 for more details.

and

> Requires a 86-64 CPU, system only detecting i866

<sup>Or something similar. I don't have the complete statement in front of me at the moment.</sup>

I went to the site they suggested and read the information but I still don't know how to fix it. What do these messages mean?

Comment: Are you sure you are running 64bit? Could you tell us what the make and model of the processor is?

Comment: Was `Kernel requires x86-64 CPU, but only detects i686` your second message? I know [this answer is for VMware under Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/380995/kernel-requires-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detects-i686-in-an-intel-intel-core-i7-26), but the tips may apply to you too

Comment: Please post a screenshot of Task Manager's CPU utilization view. It includes all relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

I only get this message when my host pc goes into "sleep" mode.

I have a guest os of Windows 10 Preview and the only cure for my problem is to reboot my host pc,  then start VMware. Then when I launch windows 10 preview all is well as long as I do NOT allow my host pc to go into "sleep" mode again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the first message ("Binary translation is incompatible...") and couldn't boot (stuck in a "Windows is loading files" reboot loop).  I resolved it by enabling "Virtualization Technology".  This was under "System Security" in the host computer's BIOS settings.